# Check if apache has a ssl certificate installed with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

Is there a away to check if apache has a ssl certificate installed with htaccess, before running any RewriteCond or RewriteRule for https?

E.g.:

Apache has ssl certificate installed then
RewriteCond {HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking "if SSL certificate exists", check "if ssl module is on" - the latter requires a certificate by itself

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: No necessarily. The fact that `mod_ssl` is loaded doesn't mean that it's configured.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't do what you claim. It doesn't test whether SSL is 'on', only whether the SSL module has been loaded. Not an answer.

Comment: @EJP: The thing is, all SSL_* variables will only be meaningfull if the ssl engine is *on*, which only happens if you're already using SSL... so the only other option i can see is to check if ssl **can** be used, and that can only happen if the module is enabled... where am i wrong here?

Comment: @Bruno won't apache fail to start if you attempt to start it up with ssl enabled but without specified sslcertfile?

Comment: @poncha, loading `mod_ssl` and enabling it (via `SSLEngine on`) are two different things. `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` only checks that the module is loaded (so as to be able to use the `SSL*` directives), it doesn't check that they're used anywhere. They could also be used in a `VirtualHost` that doesn't share the same name as the plain host, for example.

Comment: @Bruno `SSLEngine On` will be used only on the `VirtualHost` that actually runs ssl, so on an http-vhost (even with same name) this would anyway be off... hence there is no point or option of checking this... but you're right, if the sslengine is off on all the vhosts, then this would still fail

Answer (score 0):

If Apache doesn't have a certificate installed, the protocol cannot possibly be HTTPS.